# how to write the LSF file to send the output to another folder other than PWD

Tags: hpc, cd, lsf

Imagine I have a lsf file as fllows:

```
#!/bin/sh
#BSUB -J X
#BSUB -o X.out
#BSUB -e X.err
...
```

Once it is run the output will appear in the current folder.

Now imagine I am in

```
~/code
```

I need the files to appear in

```
../cluster/
```

basically go one folder back and from there go to folder cluster.

How should I write do it within the lsf file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put any relative or absolute path in `#BSUB -[eo] <file>`.  e.g. `#BSUB -e ../cluster/X.err`. If using a relative path, its relative to the job CWD. By default the job CWD is the job submission directory, but can be changed by a bunch of different parameters.  `bjobs -l <jobid>` shows the actual CWD.

What happens is that while the job is running, the stdout and stderr goes to a file under LSF_TMPDIR (default is $HOME/.lsbatch).  After the job finishes, the contents of those files is copied to the pathnames specified in `-[eo]`.  The copying is done on the execution host.